# Scan using the EPSON Scan "Professional Mode" settings without showing UI

Tags: c#, scanning, epson, twain

I'm using NTwain to interface with an Epson scanner programmatically and it works well for enabling and transferring images, as well as setting some scan settings.

However, I want to be able to set different "profiles" using `Epson Scan` in Professional Mode, then recall them programmatically in my application.  I can browse the registry and find where all these settings live, but I don't know how to get the scanner to use them without starting the scan from the `Epson Scan` application. Is this even possible? Or is there a way to map the settings to twain settings?  I noticed epson lists a [CAP_CUSTOMDSDATA](https://www.epsondevelopers.com/twain-programming-guide-epson-scan/supported-capabilities/) capability but this is unfortunately not supported with my scanner.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Although not many would know about this dedicated, proprietary application, I’d like to appreciate you as this Q&A is such a gem to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with Epson Scan technical support, it seems like this is not possible without custom firmware.  The only way to implement some of the settings provided by Epson Scan is by using the application itself.

The workaround for me was to set the appropriate registry values (located at `SOFTWARE\Epson\EPSON Scan\ES00FE\Professional`) and then opening epson scan (via `_twain.CurrentSource.Enable(SourceEnableMode.ShowUI)`) and clicking the scan button through the application.  A bit hacky but it works.